# Create Your Own Console Graphics Library in C

Tags: c, graphics, console, console-application, turbo-c++

What I need to create is something simila to the CRT unit in Pascal or the old Graphics.h in Turbo C++, I am using the MinGW compiler. Is there any way to implement the `GotoXY`,`ClrScr`,`Sleep`,'SetClr' etc. functions using, maybe the winapi kernel library or something? Or is there already a library made for MinGW that does all this. I need it to run on a Console Window, and only be text based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use curses , there's a port of pdcurses for mingw here http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Community_Supplied_Links

curses is a little odd to use, it was originally written for terminals on unix.

(You can have that sweet coloured and blincking text 90's gui)

Comment: Yay! I think that is called TUI (text user interface) now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have similar requirements for a project I've working on, so I started a project that might serve as a potential alternate answer for you.  It's still a young project, but it will grow to be a bit more useful as things go along.  It has an add-on library to integrate with ncurses, but it essentially just "renders" ANSI-encoded strings.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ansigl

Hope that helps!